# After running SELECT DISTINCT, duplicates still show

Tags: oracle, select, duplicates, distinct

I am still seeing duplicates in my results after running the `SELECT DISTINCT` despite using all the appropriate techniques to insure duplicate rows are truly duplicate (applying trim to all fields, formatting the date fields as date only etc.). I even tried `GROUP BY`, yet after running it, duplicates still showed up. Does anyone have any clue what in the world is happening, and anything I can do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, City, State, Zip, 
    to_date(START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as START_DATE, 
    to_date(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as END_DATE 
FROM 
    AddressHistory
ORDER BY 
    ID, START_DATE DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try what I suggested when you posted the same question yesterday? I don't see TRUNC applied to the dates in your query in this question. Appart from that, assuming the "dates" are indeed data type, why are you applying TO_DATE to them? TO_DATE should be applied to ***strings***, to convert them to dates.

Comment: Provide test case: CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO several sample rows ("E 3RD ST" would be enough) so that we'd see what you really have and what your query returns and why.

Comment: What is the data type of column start_date and end_date? If they are DATE types then use TRUNC - never use TO_DATE on a value which is already a DATE. If they are string data types then you may have values like "01-Jan-2020" and "01-JAN-2020" and another example why one should never store date/time values as string.

Comment: If you `select dump(column_name) from table`, you'll see exactly what each column/ expression evaluates to in a binary output and where the difference lies.  Without a reproducible example, my guess would be that one of the dates is in a century other than the one you expect (i.e. one date is in 2013 and the other is in 1913 or 0013).  But that's just a guess without more information.

Comment: @mathguy, when I do Trunc(Start_Date), I was getting the following error. This was because there were nulls in some of the records, so it was throwing the error when it encountered nulls.
That's why I tried something else, but I understand what you're saying

ORA-01722: invalid number

01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.

*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: It appears that a combination of using Trim around certain fields (to remove hidden characters) AND the trunc(to_date(START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as START_DATE approach resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     ID, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, City, State, Zip, 
     trunc(to_date(START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as START_DATE, 
     trunc(to_date(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as END_DATE  FROM 
AddressHistory 
ORDER BY ID, START_DATE DESC;
```

This truncates the times of the date and is faster than type cast conversion.

What data type is START_DATE in your example? Perhaps you can get rid of the type cast completely?

Comment: It appears that a combination of using Trim around certain fields (to remove hidden characters) AND the trunc(to_date(START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as START_DATE approach resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is because the time factor in your column `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` is not the same, you should get distinct if you write your query like following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
    SELECT  ID, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, City, State, Zip, to_date(START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as START_DATE, to_date(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as END_DATE

    FROM AddressHistory
)T

ORDER BY ID, START_DATE desc;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong (despite one upvote already). Wrong as the application of TO_DATE is in the OP's query, if it doesn't throw an error, it will result in dates with time-of-day component equal to midnight.